# Learning binary trees, can't figure out how to merge 2 code samples

Tags: java, binary-tree

How can I add/combine this binary tree:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryTreeTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    new BinaryTreeTest().run();
  }

  // Node Class
  static class Node {
    Node left;

    Node right;

    int value;

    public Node(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    // build simple tree 

    Node root = new Node(5);
    System.out.println("Binary Tree Example");
    System.out.println("Building tree with root value of ID " + root.value);
    insert(root, 1);
    insert(root, 8);
    insert(root, 6);
    insert(root, 3);
    insert(root, 9);
    System.out.println("Traversing tree in order");
    printInOrder(root);
    System.out.println("Traversing tree front-to-back from location 7");
    printFrontToBack(root, 7);
  }

  public void insert(Node node, int value) {
    if (value < node.value) {
      if (node.left != null) {
        insert(node.left, value);
      } else {
        System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to left of "
            + node.value);
        node.left = new Node(value);
      }
    } else if (value > node.value) {
      if (node.right != null) {
        insert(node.right, value);
      } else {
        System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to right of "
            + node.value);
        node.right = new Node(value);
      }
    }
  }

  public void printInOrder(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
      printInOrder(node.left);
      System.out.println("  Traversed " + node.value);
      printInOrder(node.right);
    }
  }

  /**
   * uses in-order traversal when the origin is less than the node's value
   * 
   * uses reverse-order traversal when the origin is greater than the node's
   * order
   */
  public void printFrontToBack(Node node, int id) {
    if (node == null)
      return;
    if (node.value > id) {
      // print in order
      printFrontToBack(node.left, id);
      System.out.println("  Traversed " + node.value);
      printFrontToBack(node.right, id);
    } else if (node.value < id) {
      // print reverse order
      printFrontToBack(node.right, id);
      System.out.println("  Traversed " + node.value);
      printFrontToBack(node.left, id);
    } else {
      // order doesn't matter
      printFrontToBack(node.left, id);
      printFrontToBack(node.right, id);
    }
  }

}
```

With this code, so that I can insert `Person` instances in a created binary tree:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class clubmember {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int id;
        String fname, lname;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("ID>");
        id = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Fname >");
        fname = input.next();

        System.out.println("lname >");
        lname = input.next();


        Person object1 = new Person(id, fname, lname);

        System.out.println(object1);


    }
}


public class Person {
    private final int id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;


    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(id) + ": " + firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question does not even make sense, can you clarify what exactly you are wanting to accomplish by adding a binary tree to the second bit of code?

Comment: How do I merge the binary tree to work with the code I have below it. Looking for an example of some type to get this figured out

Comment: You want to insert Persons in your binary tree? What kind of merging do you mean?

Comment: Right. I want to insert Persons in the tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Creating a binary tree in general

It would be easier and would create cleaner code to create a class named `BinaryTree` which will be something like this):

```
class Node
{
   Node left, right;
   Person value;

   public Node(Person val)  {
     value = val;
   }
}

public class BinaryTree {

   Node head;    

   public BinaryTree() {
      head = null;
   }

   public void insert(Person data) {
       Node tmp = new Node(data);
       if (head == null) head = tmp;
       else
          // do comparisons with head to decide where to add the new node
         head->left = new Node(data);
         // or head->right = new Node(data);
   }

   public void traverse() {

     // could be similar to your printInOrder method
   }

}
```

and then you could do:

```
... main(String[] args) {

   BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
   tree.insert(new Person(...));
   tree.insert(new Person(...));

   tree.traverse();

}
```

#### Make your code work with not many changes

This is more on how to "work" in your already created code.

If you want to insert `Person` instances inside a binary tree, first of all you should change:

```
  // Node Class
  static class Node {
    Node left, right;

    int value;

    public Node(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
```

instead of taking `int` values, to take `Person` instances, like this:

```
  // Node Class
  static class Node {
    Node left, right;

    Person per;

    public Node(Person per) {
      this.per = per;
    }
  }
```

You should also change `insert` method to take `Person` instances, instead of `int` values. And change the comparisons `(value < node.value)` to compare `Person` instances, maybe by their `lastName` or their `id` instead.

Then inside your `clubmember` `main` code you could do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   BinaryTreeTest foo;    


   Person per1 = new Person(...);
   BinaryTreeTest.Node nod1 = new BinaryTreeTest.Node(per1);

   Person per2 = new Person(...);

   foo.insert(nod1, per2);
```

Comment: You should also change insert method to take Person instances, instead of int values. And change the comparisons (value < node.value) to compare Person instances, maybe by their lastName or their id instead. '''How would I do that?

Comment: Like this: `public void insert(Node node, Person value) {
    if (value.id < node.value.id) {
      if (node.left != null) {
        insert(node.left, value);
      } else {
        System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to left of "
            + node.value);
        node.left = new Node(value);
      }
    } else if (value.id > node.value.id) {
      if (node.right != null) {
        insert(node.right, value);
      } else {
        System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to right of "
            + node.value);
        node.right = new Node(value);
      }
    }`

Comment: @allencoded Now `value` is a `Person` instance, so `node.value` corresponds to a `Person` `instance`, and you can read it's properites by doing `node.value.id` or `node.value.firstName` ...

Comment: When I do that though I it trying to tell me change visibility id to 'default'

Comment: sorry for my stupidity is their anyway you can clarify the above?

Comment: @allencoded That's my fault. Should have pointed this out. When you declare `id` you declare it as `private`, you do ` private final int id;`. This means, that you cannot read `id` outside of the class `Person`. You can use instead the `public` `getId()` method like this:
`public void insert(Node node, Person value) { if (value.getId() < node.value.getId()) { ... }`

Comment: that works for value.getId() but past the < sign you have node.value.getID() it tells me create field value or create constant value.

Comment: @allencoded Ok try these code examples, clubmember.java http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/udhkBQJrwB , BinaryTreeTest.java http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/UyoYuI8OoD and Person.java at http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/hCue9aEns9 . For me those 3 files worked just fine. Tell me if they worked at your pc

Comment: That worked...Thanks...Now I am going to dissect this to the 10th degree until I understand it backwards and forwards. Your code is going to teach me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is a poor abstraction - no wonder you're having trouble merging it in.  I'd recommend a BinaryTree class somewhere, preferrably one that uses generics:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> {
    // What methods do all BinaryTrees need?
}
```

You'll have an easier time integrating this data structure than what you have.

Maybe [this](http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2009/10/practice-practice-practice.html) can get you started.

Comment: thanks you are beginning to get me on the right track...sorry I am trying to learn how Binary trees still.